# How to web scrape data from a separate page that each element has in rvest?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, data-science, rvest

So I'm trying to scrape data from a site that contains club data from clubs at my school. I've got a good script going that scrapes the surface level data from the site, however I can get more data by clicking the "more information" link at each club which leads to the club's profile page. I would like to scrape the data from that page (specifically the facebook link). How can I do this?

Below you'll see my current attempt at this.

```
url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
page <- html_session(url)

get_table <- function(page, count) {
  #find group names
  name_text <- html_nodes(page,".grpl-name a") %>% html_text()
  df <- data.frame(name_text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #find text description
  desc_text <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-purpose") %>% html_text()
  df$desc_text <- trimws(desc_text)

  #find emails
  #  find the parent nodes with html_nodes
  #  then find the contact information from each parent using html_node
  email_nodes<-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-contact a") %>% html_text()
  df$emails<-email_nodes

  category_nodes <- html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node(".grpl-type") %>% html_text()
  df$category<-category_nodes

  pic_nodes <-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-logo img") %>% html_attr("src")
  df$logo <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", pic_nodes)

  more_info_nodes <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-moreinfo a") %>% html_attr("href")
  df$more_info <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", more_info_nodes)

  sub_page <- page %>% follow_link(css = ".grpl-moreinfo a")

  df$fb <- html_node(sub_page, "#dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget") %>% html_text()

  if(count != 44) {
    return (rbind(df, get_table(page %>% follow_link(css = ".paging_nav a:last-child"), count + 1)))
  } else{
    return (df)
  }
}


RSO_data <- get_table(page, 0)
```

The part where I try to get the facebook page comes here:

```
 sub_page <- page %>% follow_link(css = ".grpl-moreinfo a")

  df$fb <- html_node(sub_page, "#dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget") %>% html_text()
```

However this returns an error. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way I can scrape the data from the separate page of each club?

Answer (score 0):

use an xpath to extract the desired node, based on it's id.

```
df$fb <- html_node(sub_page, xpath = '//*[@id="dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget"]') %>% html_text()

# > html_node(sub_page, xpath = '//*[@id="dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget"]') %>% html_text()
  # [1] "https://www.facebook.com/17thavehouse/?fref=ts"
```

You will, however, need to 'loop' through all your df$name_text to open all different subpagesm and extract the facebook-links.

Comment: How can I loop through this in addition to my recursive loop?

Comment: @ConnorCarlson you (for example) an write a cutom function that you call with (m)apply. Please ask a separate question, and accept my answer if it helped you.